# "merging" two columns of two SQL databases into a third (with a catch)

Tags: mysql, database

In connection with another more complicated problem, I am doing some SQL database prototyping.  I want to do the following:

1. Take an existing SQL database that has a column called 'studentNames'
2. Take another existing SQL database that has a column called 'ACTvocabularyWords'
3. "Merge" them together in new database in such a way that I can keep up with which students have and have not mastered which ACT vocabulary words.

To clarify, here is an example of what the two original databases look like (roughly):

```
studentNames:
-------------
adam applewhite
betty boop
carl creepy . . .
```

and here is the database with the vocab words:

```
actVocabWords:
--------------------
androgynous 
ctenoid 
stygian . . .
```

The merged table (if you will) should look like:

```
studentName:          actVocabWord:           mastered:
----------------------------------------------------------------
adam applewhite       androgynous             T 
adam applewhite       ctenoid                 T 
adam applewhite       stygian                 F 
betty boop            androgynous             T 
betty boop            ctenoid                 F 
betty boop            stygian                 F 
carl creepy           androgynous             T 
carl creepy           ctenoid                 T 
carl creepy           stygian                 T
```

(my apologies for being so bad at creating tables on this site)

I'm sure there's a fairly easy way to do this kind of merging/joining, but I have no idea what to call it (so that I can search the documentation for it).

As far as I am aware, UNION, UNION ALL, OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN, BATCH INSERT and the like were never really meant to do this kind of thing.  It has also been suggested to me NOT to try to extract the data from the vocab database, load it into a list or array (in say, Java), process the merging manually, and then create a new database.

Does anyone know what I should call this strange type of "merging" so that I can read the SQL documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably talking about tables, not databases, because databases comprise tables, tables comprise columns.

Comment: @ dmitryro:  agreed -- I was using "tables" and "database" like they're interchangeable words.  Obviously, they aren't.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain how to get the last column, `mastered`.

You get the rows with a `cross join`:

```
select studentName, actVocabWord
from StudentNames sn cross join actVocabWords vw;
```

This would often be combined with another table, say `mastered` to get the flag:

```
select sn.studentName, vw.actVocabWord,
       (m.studentName is null) as mastered
from StudentNames sn cross join
     actVocabWords vw left join
     mastered m
     on m.studentName = sn.studentName and m.actVocabWord = vw.actVocabWord
```

Comment: Thanks!  Question answered!